# How to compare a URL of "file://localhost/var/mobile/..." with "file:///var/mobile/..."

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I'm opening a local file using UIWebView:loadRequest with an NSURLRequest which is in turn set from a URL.

The base location for url is obtained using:

```
    baseDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                                                        inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                                appropriateForURL:nil   
                                                                            create: YES
                                                                            error:&err];
```

This returns a URL of the form:

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/Library/ApplicationSupport/ABC/XYZ/page.html
```

However when the UIWebViewDelegate shouldStartLoadForRequest:(NSURLRequest*) method gets called the NSURLRequest that is passed has changed to the following:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/Library/ApplicationSupport/ABC/XYZ/page.html
```

Both of these therefore reference the same file, however I have a situation where I need to make a comparison between the two (I needs to compare the /ABC/XYZ/page.html parts) and NSURL:isEqual returns NO when comparing the two.

Is there either:
a) a method of NSFileManager that will return file:///var/mobile/... instead of file://localhost/var/mobile/...

or

b) easily extract just the /ABC/XYZ/page.html part and perform the comparison on that?

Comment: This problem isn't right but hear me out: Wouldn't it make sense for apple to not allow apps to get information form the **root** of the file system? Apps are *not* meant to even access simple file such as HTML files that are outside of there sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that both files will always be on the same machine, then `[[URL1 path] isEqualToString:[URL2 path]]`.

---

The following unit tests pass:

```
- (void)testURLPath
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/foo/bar/baz"];
    NSString *path = [URL path];
    STAssertEqualObjects(path, @"/foo/bar/baz", nil);
}

- (void)testURLPathCompare
{
    NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/foo/bar/baz"];
    NSURL *URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///foo/bar/baz"];
    NSString *path1 = [URL1 path];
    NSString *path2 = [URL2 path];
    STAssertTrue([path1 isEqualToString:path2], nil);
    STAssertTrue([[URL1 path] isEqualToString:[URL2 path]], nil);
}
```

Comment: But isn't the path part going to include /localhost in but not in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling `URLByStandardizingPath` on both URLs and comparing those results instead of the originals.

If that doesn't work, you could compare just the last two path components by calling `pathComponents` on both URLs and comparing the last and next-to-last objects in both returned arrays.